# How to debug issues with certificates in IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service /Certificate Manager?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress

I have a paid cluster with the IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service and a container / service deployed. I have a valid wildcard certificate which I imported into the Certificate Manager. Now I want to apply or deploy that certificate to my cluster:

`bx cs alb-cert-deploy --secret-name henrik-xxxx --cluster henrik-bla-bla --cert-crn crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloudcerts:us-south:a/lotsofnumbers:certificate:morenumbers`

The above command returns without an error. But when I check the certificate deployment with `alb-cert-get` it reports a "create_failed". I looked at the [troubleshooting guide](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_troubleshoot_network.html#cs_albsecret_fails) and tried to update and remove the certificate resp. secret. However, it seems the secret is still around and I cannot really remove it.

Are there command options I can use to get more diagnostic data? Any logs I can see? Any command I can use to clean up the environment?

Comment: After talking to the dev team, they suggested that you open a [support ticket](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/howtogetsupport.html#getting-customer-support) and include the cluster details and the output of `bx cs alb-certs --cluster <cluster-name>` as well as `bx cs alb-cert-get --cluster <cluster-name> --secret <secret-name>`.
The team must look into the logs for the albcert service to find out why the create/delete is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to debug the issue:

1. Use `export BLUEMIX_TRACE=true; bx cs alb-cert-deploy ...` to trace the command.
2. Use the [Activity Tracker](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/activity-tracker) service and account-level events.

In my case I could see the following in the Activity Tracker logs:

```
"responseData_str": "{\"code\":\"IAMERR403-01\",\"message\":\"Forbidden\"}",
```

It was part of an event related to:

```
"action_str": "cloudcerts.certificate.read",
    "target": {
      "name_str": "cloudcerts",
      "id_str": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloudcerts:us-south:a/lotsofnumberhere::",
      "typeURI_str": "certificate/read"
    },
```

This points to an authorization issue.